# Change nodejs temporary directory

Tags: node.js

I want to make file upload using nodejs, but fs.rename() cannot move a file between two different disks/partitions, I don't want to copy uploaded file from temporary directory. 
I want to change temporary directory so fs.rename() will work.

how can i do that? thanks!

Comment: The temporary directory for what? Which module are you using to manage file uploads?

Comment: the temporary directory for uploaded files, i think require("os").tmpdir(). i am using express and formidable

Comment: try changing this in either your app.js or express.js, app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + "/public/img" })); change the /public/img path to where you want your file to be saved. __dirname is your project folder path, you can give that path manually also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module responsible for that is [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable), and you can set `uploadDir`, as per the README:

> ```
> form.uploadDir = "/my/dir";
> ```
>
> Sets the directory for placing file uploads in. You can move them
>   later on using `fs.rename()`. The default is `os.tmpDir()`.