# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I just deployed my first nodejs app to heroku that contains file upload option it working fine in my local host but not in heroku when I checked heroku log it says Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/upload_b7273eba4e1532df2526c225f550de61' -> '/app/routes./uploads/data/1f86e8b13b3e0f95c8ef4d61f8d515ad.pdf'

my code looks like this

```
routes.post('/',(req,res) => {
var form=new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req,(err,fields,files) => {
    //Check file type
    console.log(files.resume.type);
    if(files.resume.type !== 'image/jpeg' && files.resume.type !== 'application/pdf' && files.resume.type !== 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' && files.resume.type !== 'application/msword'){
        res.render('upload',{msg:"Resume must be in jpg,doc,docx,pdf format"})
    }else{
    //If in resume format
        crypto.randomBytes(16,(err,buf) => {
            if(err) { return err}
            const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(files.resume.name);        
            var old_path=files.resume.path;
            console.log(old_path);

            var new_path=path.join(__dirname+'./uploads/data/' + filename);
            console.log(new_path);

            fs.rename(old_path,new_path,(err) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log("File Uploaded");
            res.render('upload',{msg:"Upload success"})      
            })

        });  
    }

})


});
```

my old_path on heroku is /tmp/upload_b7273eba4e1532df2526c225f550de61 and new_path is /app/routes./uploads/data/1f86e8b13b3e0f95c8ef4d61f8d515ad.pdf

Comment: Ahem! Is this your card: [Change nodejs temporary directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423157/change-nodejs-temporary-directory)

Comment: Where should i use form.uploadDir='../uploads/data'; in my code ?? I have no idea about this and didn't find any tutorial regarding this

Comment: Note that Heroku does not persist files. Not a big deal if this isn't a production project, but any files will be erased when the Heroku dyno sleeps.

Comment: Anytime after `var form=new formidable.IncomingForm();` The general sentiment being that `/tmp` is likely not a reliable source on any system you do not control. Rather than `rename()` you probably should just set the upload directory to where you want things to go. Most libraries for multi-part uploads support a similar concept.

Comment: This is not for production this is just for test and my learning because godaddy donesn't allow to install node js in my shared hosting account so i'm testing my code on heroku

Comment: Hey guys finally I solved my problem using fs.writefile

Comment: But now how should I access that file from heroku ??

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

Put `form.uploadDir` equal to the desired landing point for your uploads before you use `form.parse()`.

### Explanation

I recently ran into this same issue so I decided to post what I found to help others who find their way here.

As Neil Lunn points out, need to set the uploads directory for formidable. The default is `os.tempDir()`. On Windows this usually looks something like:
`C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\`

Since this location doesn't always exists be default, it throws an error. You just need to set up a location for your formidable uploads to land, and you have to do it before you `parse()` the form. For example:

```
let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, "uploads");
form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {...
```

This will set your landing point to a directory in the same location as your server.js or App.js file called `uploads/`.

You can then rename the path of the files you uploaded to match that location and access them there. For Example:

```
fs.renameSync(files.file.path, "uploads/" + fields.fileName);
```

Then you can access your file as

```
fs.readFileSync("uploads/" + fields.fileName);
```